# ASP.NET page life cycle and javascript events

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages, jquery-events, ascx

I have the following setup -

[image]

During the `page_load(...)` of each item, I register a jQuery `window-onresize` event to size each control depending on the size of its parent control.

The problem -- The `window.resize` events don't occur in the order I want them to because `page_load()` for the aspx page occurs, then the master pages.

Using `height="100%"` in CSS is not possible because of padding and margins.
Are there general strategies for dealing with this situation? I could use other page and control lifecycle events however, that seems a bit hacky.

I need suggestions; I've thought of assigning each control a precedence score and registering them with some global JS object and then run it in that order. Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea (assuming you can use jQuery):

Register innermost child's `onresize` only. Then inside that `onresize`, call `$(this).parent().trigger('onresize');`

That will ensure it bubbles up the chain correctly.

Note: If you don't use jQuery, you can still implement this event bubbling in javascript.